# Selenium Parallel testing with extension methods

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2012, nunit-3.0

I have configured tests to run in parallel in Selenium with Nunit which works fine but I'm not sure how to add a custom method into the mix without a second instance of the browser opening and breaking the test.

I have the Base:

```
namespace ParallelTests
{
   public class Base
   {
       public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
   }
}
```

...and the Hooks:

```
public class Hooks : Base
{
   public Hooks()
   {
      Driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\Data\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ParallelTests\ParallelTests\bin");
   }
}
```

...and a single test file:

```
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
public class ChromeTesting: Hooks
{
    [Test]
    public void ChromegGoogleTest()
    {
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.uk");
        Driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Deep Purple");
        Driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    }
}
```

Running this works fine, but if I add a custom method, say:

```
public class ExtensionMethods : Hooks
{
    public void assertDisplayed()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'Some Text')]")).Displayed);
    }
}
```

and call `assertDisplayed()` in the test such as:

```
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
public class ChromeTesting: Hooks
{
  [Test]
  public void ChromegGoogleTest()
  {
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.uk");
    Driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Deep Purple");
    Driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    ExtensionMethods.assertDisplayed();
  }
}
```

It will launch a second blank browser when I call `assertDisplayed()` in the test shown above. Any help much appreciated.

Now working based on suggestions but below is an example with page object model which again launches a second browser window...

**Page File:**

```
namespace ParallelTests
{
class PageObject_LoggedIn : Hooks
{
  public PageObject_LoggedIn()
  {
      PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
  }

  [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = @"//*[contains(text(),'Deep Purple | Official Site')]")]
  public IWebElement SearchText = null;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "lst-ib")]
    public IWebElement SearchBox = null;

    public void Search()
    {
        SearchBox.SendKeys("Deep Purple");
        SearchBox.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        Driver.assertDisplayed2();
    }
}
```

}

...and calling in the test...
**Test code:**

```
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
public class ChromeTesting: Hooks
{
    [Test]
    public void ChromegGoogleTest()
    {
        PageObject_LoggedIn loggedIn = new PageObject_LoggedIn();

        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.uk");
        loggedIn.Search();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the assertDisplayed method? Can we see the code?

Comment: Sorry yes, I have added this now, thanks.

Comment: Sorry but that code will not even compile because assertDisplayed is not a  static method.

Comment: This is happening because `ExtensionMethods` inherits from `Hooks` which creates a new driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there are a few things you need to change. Extension methods have a few rules which we need to follow. The rules are:

1. It must be in a non generic static class. So the method must be static since you cannot have instance methods in a static class.
2. It must have one parameter and the first parameter must have `this` keyword. The first parameter cannot have `out` or `ref`.
3. The first parameter cannot be a pointer type.

So keeping those rules in mind, let's go ahead and create the extension method you need.

```
namespace ParallelTests
{
    public static class ExtensionMethods // I would call it ChromeDriverEntension
    {
        public static void AssertDisplayed(this IWebDriver driver)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'Some Text')]")).Displayed);
        }
    }
}
```

The above is a nongeneric static class. It has one parameter and the first parameter has this keyword. The first parameter is IWebDriver since this is what we are extending. The method is also static.

Ok let's go ahead and use it.

```
namespace ParallelTests
{
    public class Base
    {
        public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hooks : Base
    {
        public Hooks()
        {
            Driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    public class ChromeTesting : Hooks
    {
        [Test]
        public void ChromegGoogleTest()
        {
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.uk");
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Deep Purple");
            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
            Driver.AssertDisplayed();
        }
    }
}
```

**How the compiler finds the extension method?**

When the compiler notices code which looks like instance method, `Driver.AssertDisplayed();`, but there is no instance method that satisfies the signature, then it looks for an extension method. It searches all the namespaces to find a match. Since this method is in the same namespace above, it will find it. If it was in a different namespace, you would need to import that namespace with `using A.B` where A.B is the name of the namespace where the extension method is. Otherwise, the compiler will generate an error saying it cannot find such a method.

C# in Depth by Jon Skeet covers extension methods in depth if you want to read more.

Comment: Thanks, am new to all this, but when I do that I get 'ParallelTests.Base.Driver' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type' and that the extension method must be static. But that won't work as 'public class ExtensionMethods : Hooks' would need to be static which it can't be as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Sorry see my edit. You need to pass ChromeDriver into it.

Comment: Thanks but i still get 'Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class' for 'public class ExtensionMethods : Hooks', as I mentioned.

Comment: I thought you would know that. Just make ExtensionMethods static.

Comment: I did try that but then the assertDisplayed in the test isn't recognised.

Comment: If you are still having issues tomorrow i will create a sample and share it with you. I do not have my computer with me right now. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129722/discussion-between-alex-and-codingyoshi).