# Selenium C# parallel testing using single driver\browser

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2012

I have a project which uses the page object model and I've edited it to try and use parallel testing with Nunit. However when I run one single test it will launch a second unwanted browser. I think this is where I'm initiating my page at the beginning of the test.

The files I have are a Base class for the driver:

```
namespace ParallelTests
{
  public class Base
  {
     public static IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
  }
}
```

A hooks file to setup the driver:

```
namespace ParallelTests
{
  public class Hooks : Base
  {
    public Hooks()
    {
        Driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\Data\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ParallelTests\ParallelTests\bin");
    }
  }
}
```

The page file:

```
namespace ParallelTests
{
class PageObject_LoggedIn : Hooks
{
    public PageObject_LoggedIn()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "lst-ib")]
    public IWebElement SearchBox = null;

    public void Search()
    {
        SearchBox.SendKeys("Deep Purple");
        SearchBox.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    }
}
}
```

And the test itself:

```
[TestFixture]
[Parallelizable]
public class ChromeTesting : Hooks
{
    [Test]
    public void ChromegGoogleTest()
    {
        PageObject_LoggedIn loggedIn = new PageObject_LoggedIn();

        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.uk");
        loggedIn.Search();
    }
}
```

I think it's `PageObject_LoggedIn loggedIn = new PageObject_LoggedIn();` in the test which is launching the second browser but I'm not sure how to rectify it.

This is an extension to an original issue, but is treated as a separate issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Parallel testing with extension methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952942/selenium-parallel-testing-with-extension-methods)

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question you asked yesterday... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952942/selenium-parallel-testing-with-extension-methods

Comment: Sorry I was told it was better to put in a new question as this is separate to the original issue

Comment: What code do you have in InitElements?

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand? All the files and code I have for this example are shown.

Comment: The question you asked in both of these is, "How do I prevent a second browser from opening." I'm not sure how they are different? My comment in the other question told you why the issue is occurring and you have an answer that explains how to fix it.

Comment: Yes that's correct the first example was fixed by your suggestion but when adding in the POM the same thing happens but I can't use the same solution as the page class file can't be static

Comment: Hi, okay apologies I think I understand now. I wasn't sure how to apply the logic from the original fix to the POM. I have it working now and will add the updated code shortly.

Comment: Duplicate of resolved question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952942/selenium-parallel-testing-with-extension-methods)